# Embed Angular expression in CakePHP html helper

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cakephp, html-helper

I want to embed angularjs expression in html helper like this.

```
<td><?php

echo $this->html->link(_('{{row.Document.name}}'), array('controller' => 'documents', 'action' => 'edit', '_({{row.Document.id}})'));
?>
</td>
```

In this code, it's able get the name parameter correct, but not the id, just wondering how it can be fixed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because it will URL encode `'_({{row.Document.id}})'` this.

Don't use the helper or extend the helper and overload the methods with code like this:

```
$url = Router::url($url);
foreach ($options['unescapedParams'] as $param) {
    $url .= $param;
}
```

And pass the params you don't want to get escaped via the options. I wouldn't use the helper at all. My experience is that I usually have so many Angular specific things in the view that using the helpers for forms (that are completely processed by Angular any way) is just ending up in having a huge $options array with all the Angular attributes.